# Start Quarkus Application on test port for custom goal

Tags: quarkus

I have a Quarkus application that automatically runs on the configured test port when I run mvn test. This works for both RestAssured and Karate tests I have for the API testing.

I am using Karate/Gatling tests to do performance testing, and I trigger these performance using gatling:test goal. Is there a way I can start my Quarkus application on test port automatically when I trigger gatling:test goal.

Basically, I want to have the application start automatically before my performance testing.

Appreciate any guidance.

Comment: When starting Quarkus in test mode, you will not have the same performance characteristic that running in production mode (not the same classloader, nor the same packaging - exploded classes vs jar). Moreover, running your application via Maven uses by default certain JVM parameters optimized for short living apps. 
So I strongly  suggest packaging the JAR and running it prior to launching the Gatling benchmark.

Comment: Thats a good point. Thank you.